# Gunicorn not picking stderr

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a Flask app with the following route:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    log = logging.getLogger("asdasd")
    log.addHandler(console)
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    log.error("Something")
    print >> sys.stderr, "Another thing"
    return 'ok'
```

I run this using

```
python gunicorn --access-logfile /mnt/log/test.log --error-logfile /mnt/log/test.log --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --workers 2 --worker-class gevent --log-level debug server:app
```

The Logs are as below:

```
2014-06-26 00:13:55 [21621] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
2014-06-26 00:13:55 [21626] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21626
2014-06-26 00:13:55 [21627] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21627
2014-06-26 00:14:05 [21626] [DEBUG] GET /
10.224.67.41 - - [26/Jun/2014:00:14:14 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 525 "-" "python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.5 Darwin/13.2.0"
2014-06-26 00:14:14 [21626] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
```

What's happening to my logs in index method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Gunicorn 19.0, gunicorn has stopped redirecting stderr to its logs.

Refer to https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/commit/41523188bc05fcbba840ba2e18ff67cd9df638e9